# log4net - logging to database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I'm using Log4net in ASP.Net MVC for logging to different output types (file & DB). I'm able to log data to `RollingFileAppender` but not to `AdoNetAppender`

*Added new **log4net.config** to project with `file-appender section` & `DBLog-appender section`*

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="DBLog" />
  </root>
  <!--Rolling File Appender-->
  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Trinadh\Dot.Net\Web Applications\ASP.NetMVC\PartialViewApplSol\PartialViewApplSol\myapp.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-7p%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt} –%X{user}– %m method:%method %n stacktrace:%stacktrace{5} %n %logger %n type:%type %n line: %line %n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
<!--Database Table Appender-->
  <appender name="DBLog" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="Server=DBServer;Database=DemoDB;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=sysAdmin;Password=XyzAbc;" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.Log4net_Log ([Date],[Level],[Logger],[User],[Message],[Exception])
 VALUES (@log_date, @log_level, @logger, @user, @message, @exception)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%p" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%c" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@user" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%X{user}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%m" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="2000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

In **'DBLog'** appender section, i'm using connection string of my DB to which logs would be written, but i'm already using same connection string in 'web.config' to fetch data and populate on UI.

- How to use the same connection string specified in web.config for
  logging data to table using log4net without using it here again in
  'log4net.config'.
- As i'm logging different parameters to file such as    time,
  userName, method and stacktrace; All log levels (Info, warn,
  error) log complete parameters, which i'm not interested in. How to
  log only time, userName, method under INFO level & time, userName,
  method, stacktrace under WARN/ Error level

*Added a new **log4netHelper.cs** to project*

```
public class log4netHelper  
{    
    private static readonly ILog log4Net = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);    
    public log4netHelper()    
    {    
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)    
            MDC.Set("user", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);    
    }    
    public static void LogMessage(string message)    
    {    
        log4Net.Info(message);    
    }    

    public static void LogError(string message, Exception ex)    
    {    
        log4Net.Error(message, ex);    
    }    
}
```

`RollingFileAppender`is logging following

> INFO   2018-07-23 19:27:06 PM –(null)– Index Action End
>   method:***LogMessage***
>   stacktrace:System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback >
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute >
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke >
>   PartialViewApplSol.Controllers.HomeController+<>c.b__3_1 >
>   PartialViewApplSol.App_Start.log4netHelper.LogMessage
>   PartialViewApplSol.App_Start.log4netHelper
>   type:PartialViewApplSol.App_Start.log4netHelper   line: 19

- How to get current caller method which is calling log4net.Message()? It's always showing method names in 'log4netHelper.cs' (LogMessage/ LogError). MSDN says to use 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName'
  attribute, but how to incorporate this into my logic.
- Current log4net.config have both RollingFileAppender & AdoNetAppender
  but only RollingFileAppender is logging data to file, nothing is
  logged to Database table.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is in log4net, you can best enable log4net internal debugging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And write it to file:

```
<configuration>
...

<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
            <add 
                name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>

...
</configuration>
```

If there is any exception you will find it in the log file. You already have set the buffersize to 1, that will flush each message directly.

[more on Log4net Troubleshooting](https://thinkrethink.net/2017/07/03/log4net-troubleshooting/)